# How to click hidden buttons in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm working on simple automation in Selenium. I need to click a specific button. I can't because it is hidden in div/table without class.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the html. I did try xpath, css select, select and still nothing.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjeRk.jpg)

Comment: Post your html in text format.Screenshot doesn't help other contributor to help you.Please post your code as well what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the button you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.nightclubs.unstyled > li > table.table.table-condensed button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-small.pull-right"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='nightclubs unstyled']/li/table[@class='table table-condensed']//button[@class='btn btn-inverse btn-small pull-right' and contains(., 'Wejd')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: You are my hero :) Thanks sir !

Answer (score 0):

You could try clicking the div then. You can use XPath to locate the button element (as it has some class so you can locate it) and add 
`/parent::div` to get the div to click it.